# C# multithreaded windows service, private or [ThreadStatic]

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of converting a console application I wrote from a single windows service to a windows service that supports multithreading.  However, this is my first go around with multithreads.

I was wondering if I should make every class private static instead of public static and for anything that has to remain public, attach the  [ThreadStatic] attribute.

Basically the code does a lot of string work from HTML Crawling and then places select data in a mysql database.

Comment: There's not going to be a one-size-fits-all answer to this, especially when you're not providing much detail. The devil is almost always in the small details when dealing with multithreaded code.

Comment: i hope my edit gave enough detail

Comment: Nope! Like I said, it's the small details that count, and if we can't see those small details then we can't really comment on them.

Comment: Threading gives you more cpu cycles.  Which is not what you need here.  You need more network cards and database engines.  Be careful committing to code that's hard to get right when there's so little to be gained.  The basic smell test is observing cpu load for your current app.  If it doesn't burn close to 100% on one core then adding another core won't make it more efficient.  My guess is that it is but a few percent right now.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is no; adapting your code to support multiple threads does not (necessarily) mean you need to change member or type accessibility.

As to your second question, use the `ThreadStatic` on fields (not types) if you need each thread to have its own independent static field (otherwise all threads will share the same static field).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, it feels dirty. I would rather create some kind of management class to manage all objects and pass the values between them.